# JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException when calling save() for an Entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, h2

New to Spring, I'm building a toy car dealership. This is my Entity class for cars:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Car {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
  private String vin;
  private String make;
  private String model;
  private Integer year;
  private Long cost;

  public Car() {}

  public Car(String vin, String make, String model, Integer year, Long cost) {
    this.vin = vin;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.cost = cost;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Car car = (Car) o;
    return Objects.equals(id, car.id)
        && Objects.equals(vin, car.vin)
        && Objects.equals(make, car.make)
        && Objects.equals(model, car.model)
        && Objects.equals(year, car.year)
        && Objects.equals(cost, car.cost);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id, vin, make, model, year, cost);
  }


}
```

My repository class extends `CrudRepository`:

```java
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {
.
.
.
```

My service interface:

```java
public interface DealershipService {

  Long getRevenue();

  void sell(Car car);

  void buy(Car car);
.
.
.
```

And its implementation of `buy(Car car)`:

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
@Service
public class DealershipServiceImpl implements DealershipService {

  @Value("${revenue}")
  private Long revenue;
  private final CarRepository carRepository;

  @Autowired
  public DealershipServiceImpl(CarRepository carRepository) {
    this.carRepository = carRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void buy(Car car) {
    if (revenue >= car.getCost()) {
      carRepository.save(car);
      revenue -= car.getCost();
      log.info("Bought car {}. Current revenue: {}", car, revenue);
    } else {
      log.warn("Unable to buy car {}; we're broke!", car);
      throw new InsufficientRevenueException();
    }
  }

.
.
.
```

I have the following test:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes =  TestConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class DealershipServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private  DealershipService dealershipService;

    @Test
    public void whenMakingTransactions_revenueIsAffected(){
        Car car = new Car("1234", "Nissan", "Sentra", 2012, 12_000L);
        dealershipService.buy(car);
        assertThat(dealershipService.getRevenue(), is(990_000L));
    }
}
```

When the code hits the line of `DealershipServiceImpl` where I call `save()` on the Car instance, I get the following exception:

```
2023-03-08T07:09:27.757-05:00  WARN 22592 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42104, SQLState: 42S04
2023-03-08T07:09:27.758-05:00 ERROR 22592 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "CAR" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into car (cost, make, model, vin, year, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42104-214]
2023-03-08T07:09:27.868-05:00  INFO 22592 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-03-08T07:09:27.870-05:00  INFO 22592 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2023-03-08T07:09:27.881-05:00  INFO 22592 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-03-08T07:09:27.887-05:00  INFO 22592 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into car (cost, make, model, vin, year, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:565)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:409)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy104.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.jason.cardealership.service.impl.DealershipServiceImpl.buy(DealershipServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.jason.cardealership.service.DealershipServiceIT.whenMakingTransactions_revenueIsAffected(DealershipServiceIT.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3419)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4073)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:612)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:483)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2234)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1930)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CAR" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into car (cost, make, model, vin, year, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42104-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8328)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1632)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:327)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    ... 108 more
```

Considering that I've tagged my `Car` as an `@Entity`, I'm not sure why I'm getting that exception about the database being empty. Any help appreciated. If it matters, here are my spring-data-jpa and h2 dependencies in the pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? `Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "CAR" not found (this database is empty);`

Answer (score 1):

As @tgdavies mentioned in his comment, the CAR table does not exist in your database. This is most likely because by default Hibernate won't create it. You a have to set it up in your `application.yml`. To be more specific you need these 2 properties set up correctly:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
```

The Hibernate property can have other values depending on your environment / use case. You can read about this more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Add @Table annotation into Car class and check it...!! Which will create table name with car. If we want to use different name from entity then we need to use @Table(name="[Table name we want]")

Comment: Ah, unfortunately this did not work, I'm getting the same error =/

Comment: Did you write this line in properties file ? 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update